# turn sql rows into links on a vb.net page?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to create a specific aspx page where I display clickable links based on information in a sql database.  For example one column could be the anchor tag another column could be the path to the link itself etc.  In the past I would pull this information from sql and put it into a non-visible Label (say linkLabel1). Then in the page itself I would insert `<%linkLabel1.text%>` to insert the link path from the database to the appropriate area.

I hope I'm not confusing things too much here and that makes sense how I explained it.

What I would like to do is set up a way that I could simply enter a new row into a SQL table with link information and a web page automatically displays the new link for me.

I guess I am mostly looking for insight, opinions, or directions of what approach to consider.  I can elaborate if I was unclear (wouldn't be awfully surprising if I was not).

Thanks in advance for anyone's time on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are displaying this in a table, you could use a GridView for this. The columns that will display the link could be defined as hyperlink columns as so:

```
     <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField
             HeaderText="Header text"
             DataNavigateUrlFields="PropertyContainingTheHRefForTheAnchor"
             DataTextField="PropertyContainingTheTextForTheAnchor"
             />
     </Columns>
```

So for example, if you return a record set containing these columns:

```
TextProperty             PathProperty
See Details              Assets/SomeOther/
Click me                 Products/AnotherPath/
```

Your grid will render these as:

```
<a href="Assets/SomeOther/">See Details</a>
<a href="Products/AnotherPath/">Click me</a>
```

If you define the column as:

```
     <Columns>
       <asp:HyperLinkField
             HeaderText="Header text"
             DataNavigateUrlFields="PathProperty"
             DataTextField="TextProperty"
             />
     </Columns>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I didn't realize gridview had that possibility.  Is this in the properties or can I only enter it into the code like your above example?

Comment: If you click on the arrow next to the grid in the designer and click on edit columns you can add this column without pasting in the Tags

Comment: @BradtotheBone I Am not sure I understand your question... You can declare this either from the markup (as I showed on my example) or you can access this programmatically.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a run at it and hope for the best.  I'm still a beginner as you can see and I'm self-taught so I'm not very fluent in the jargon quite yet.  I appreciate the help very much though and I'll let you know how it goes.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well that was stunningly easy.  Thanks again for the help, it worked like a charm and you are my new hero.